# South Indian filter not brewing properly

Tags: drip-brew, filter

For quite a long time I am using a [south Indian filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_filter_coffee#/media/File:Disassembled_South_Indian_coffee_filter.jpg). Earlier I used to brew without using the middle small instrument which looks like the one used in a french press for "pressing". It still used to give me a good brew. In few minutes I used to get a fresh brew. I don't know why, but suddenly it is taking longer to finish the brew and sometimes (mostly from the second time) the water doesn't even go down. It just stays in the upper part of the instrument. The [coffee powder](https://mysoreconcernscoffee.com/) I use is unchanged and so is the filter. I checked if the pores of the filter are blocked, but that is also not the case. They are all clearly opened. I wash it regularly. I tried using and not using the middle pressing instrument. No effect on the result. So I don't know what's exactly wrong and why this sudden change has happened. One thing that is different is that I have stored the coffee powder for a longer while this time (still not more than half a month). Can it make a difference? Does the powder have a shelf-life? Has anyone faced this problem? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the coffee has absorbed moisture while stored.

I'd suggest buying some very fresh coffee and trying that.

If the problem goes away, it's the old coffee that's the problem.
If the problem still happens with the new coffee, *then* is the time to investigate what is wrong with the hardware.

Comment: Okay, sure, will try and confirm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You were right. The coffee powder was moist. Using some from a new pack solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Clean up the holes in the gravity filter. Invisible residue from the brew tends to get stuck there. You can heat it up on flame so that it falls off on it's own. This can be done before every brew.

Comment: This very brief reply to an older Question omits mention of the earlier Answer and its acceptance by the original poster. Best practice in posting late Answers is to read over the previous content and contrast your response with those points.  Once you've earned 50 reputation points you will be able to Comment on the posts of others, in cases where you don't want to write more detailed replies.